# Load balancing outgoing connections in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, microservices, cloud-computing, azure

I'm currently developing an app using the [Azure Service Fabric](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/). My question comes in regards to balancing outgoing connections. One of my services is going to be making a large number of outgoing connections to remote services. I'd like to be able to load balance these connections out, so when nodes go up, the new node would need to take over for some of the connections of the other nodes. When a node goes down, the other nodes would need to take care of the connections that were just destroyed.

What would be the recommended approach to this problem?

Comment: You may want to ask this on StackOverflow. Some SF experts and members of the SF team watch for SF-specific questions there. But assuming your connections are short-lived, or that a connection is resilient enough to survive disconnect/reconnect without losing data, you should be able to load-balance through partitioning, with the connection reference determining the partition. I'm working on my first significant SF application myself, and wouldn't want to lead you down the wrong path, so I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HiredMind. I ended up looking at partitioning myself, and it does seem to be the correct way to go. I'm currently integrating the azure service bus, and setting using that to pass the incoming messages to the other services.